Difference between two dates - method missing error
The code is as follows
pickup_time = DateTime.parse(q[:payload]["pickup_time"])

     => Wed, 24 Apr 2024 00:38:00 +0000 

created_at = q[:created_at]
 => Tue, 23 Apr 2024 03:53:45.874273000 UTC +00:00 

I need to get the difference between pickup_time and created_at in hours.
I have tried
(pickup_time - q[:created_at] / 1.hour)

It outputs the following error
 `method_missing': undefined method `/' for Tue, 23 Apr 2024 03:53:45.874273000 UTC +00:00:Time (NoMethodError) 

Any idea on how to how to fix this?

The issue lies in the way you're trying to perform the calculation. q[:created_at] is a Time object, and you're attempting to divide it directly, which isn't allowed. To calculate the difference in hours between pickup_time and created_at, you need to subtract one Time or DateTime object from another, which results in a Rational difference in days. Then, you convert the result to hours if you dont need rational precission.
pickup_time = DateTime.parse("2024-04-24T00:38:00+00:00")
created_at = Time.parse("2024-04-23T03:53:45.874273+00:00")

difference_in_hours = (pickup_time - created_at.to_datetime) * 24
puts difference_in_hours# difference_in_hours.to_f if you dont need rational precission 


The error occurs because q[:created_at] is a Time object, and the division operator / is not defined for Time. To calculate the difference between two DateTime or Time objects in hours, you need to subtract them first, which returns a Rational object representing the difference in days. Then, you can convert it to hours.
Here's how you can calculate the difference in hours:
pickup_time = DateTime.parse(q[:payload]["pickup_time"])
created_at = q[:created_at]

Calculate the difference in hours
difference_in_hours = ((pickup_time - created_at.to_datetime) * 24).to_f

If pickup_time and created_at are already Time objects, you can use to_f to calculate the difference directly in seconds and then convert it to hours:
difference_in_hours = (pickup_time.to_f - created_at.to_f) / 3600


You have a syntax error with the ")". It should be like this:
(pickup_time - q[:created_at]) / 1.hour


does not work. It shows same error

make sure that, the result of (pickup_time - q[:created_at]) is a float value. DateTime / float situation must be causing this error.

(pickup_time - q[:created_at])
/Users/prajeeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb:104:in `-': expected numeric (TypeError
